# How to change mediaelement to scale in portrait and fullscreen in landscape mode on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am having difficulty trying to change the `<mediaelement />` to fullscreen automatically when the phone is rotated in landscape mode. Right now, the video will play fullscreen when I tap the lower right button that scales to full screen when I tap on it, but I don't want that. In portrait mode, I am trying to make the `<mediaelement />` fit according to the width of the phone's screen and I'm not sure how to do so or what I'm doing wrong with layout issues.

Here's the layout I have in XAML:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Height="250" Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MediaElement x:Name="media"
                  Source="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
                  AutoPlay="True"
                  AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Stretch="UniformToFill"
                  Width="Auto"
                  Height="Auto"
                      />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**UPDATED CODE for Orientation Changes:**

I debugged this method and it will go through the if statement when the phone is in landscape mode, but when I tilt the phone in portrait, it doesn't recognize anything. What I am I missing to recognize portrait event handler when the phone is put into portrait? MediaElement seems stuck in `IsFullWindow = true` and never checks again for orientationchanged event method to become `IsFullWindow = false`.

```
void MainPage_OrientationChanged(DisplayInformation sender, object args)
{
    var orientation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().CurrentOrientation; // get the current orientation of the display
    if (orientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape || orientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped) // if the orientation is landscape...
    {
        media.IsFullWindow = true; // puts the media element in full screen while in landscape
    }
    else //if (orientation == DisplayOrientations.Portrait || orientation == DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped)
    {
        media.IsFullWindow = false; // puts the media element out of full screen in portrait
        //media.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width; // set bounds of video width to width of screen
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to set `IsFullWindow="True"` in your media element property in XAML with this the media element would play in full screen no matter the orientation.(Though its always going to be in landscape mode). You can also set the media element property `IsFullWindow` as true using C# as per your requirement

Comment: Post updated on how to recognize portrait event handler when the phone is put into portrait? MediaElement seems stuck in IsFullWIndow = true and never checks again for orientationchanged event method.

Comment: As I said its FullWindow=true will always be in landscape mode no matter the orientation. Since you didnt want it to be maximized now. You would need to specify in orientation changed save the position of media element in a variable stop it then set its source. And now Inside mediaOpened event specify if you want the player to stop its full screen mode or  and resume it from the position that it was playing before.